# Sending Blob data from Angular6 client to Spring Boot API as MultipartFile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to upload audio as a MultiPart file to a Spring Boot API.  i've never done anything similar in a Angular2.x app so not sure at all if my approach is correct.  I keep getting a 500 error from the api and think it might be that my audio data is not sent in the correct format...  Am I missing something here?  I looked at the code of a gui for the same API that was done using javaFX in that gui the audio was recorded, saved as wav and then sent to the api endpoint.  Should I first save a .wav file of the audio recording and then read/send it to the API or can I use the Blob as i'm currently doing?

my code:

```
the Kotlin/spring boot endpoint:@PostMapping("/vb/Verify")
    fun verify(@RequestParam("Audio") file:MultipartFile,
               @RequestParam(name = "SessionID") sessionId: String,
               @RequestParam(name = "Risk") risk: String,
               @RequestParam(name = "Strategy") strategy:String,
               @RequestParam(name = "AudioType") audioType:String,
               @RequestParam(name = "Channel") channel:String):VerifyResponseDTO {

        val audioBytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(file.inputStream)
        return vbService.verify(sessionId, audioBytes, audioType, strategy, channel, Risk.byCode(risk))

    }


my angular component code:


constructor(private restService: RestService) {
    const onSuccess = stream => {
      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      this.mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {
        const audio = new Audio();
        const blob = new Blob(this.chunks, {type : 'audio/wav'});
        this.chunks.length = 0;
        audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);                
        this.verify(blob);
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
      };

      this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => this.chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, onSuccess, e => console.log(e));
  }

verify(blob: Blob) {
    this.restService.startSession()
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.restService.verify(blob)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }



my Angular Service verify function:
verify(blob: Blob): Observable<any> {     
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append("SessionID", "neld02");
    formData.append("Strategy", "Phrase");
    formData.append("AudioType", "Header");
    formData.append("Risk", "Lo")
    formData.append("Channel", "Smart")
    formData.append('Audio', blob);   
    formData.append("Text", "");


    return this.hc.post(`${this.api}/Verify`, formData);
   }
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the backend to see *why* it's returing a 500? Can you see what error it's throwing?

Comment: I havent,  i was just unsure about my approach on the frontend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring to the @RequestParam("Audio") **file:MultipartFile**,

I had similiar issues, could you try to map the blob to a file() Object?

```
  const file = new File([blob], 'audio.wav');
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('File', file, file.name); // file.name was mandatory for us (otherwise again an error occured)
```

Comment: No that didn't do it, it seems like the audio still isn't wav format, I get the following error from nuance voice verification: 2018-10-10 09:30:38.927 DEBUG 31396 --- [nio-8110-exec-2] c.xib.vodacom.ans.service.NuanceService  : Nuance Verify response Nuance.VB.BadAudioFormatException: Not a Wav file

Comment: Could you please check in Chrome developer tools in your Call Request your **Form Data** there click on view source and check what your content type is. It should look like this: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="image.jpeg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: question. How do you playback the audio in angular?. Multipart file contains audio data as byte[]. How do you plat that back in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestPart` for file and another `@RequestPart` to encapsulate metadata audio properties:

```
@PostMapping("/vb/Verify")
fun verify(@RequestPart(value = "audio") file:MultipartFile,
           @RequestPart(value = "audioMetadata") properties: AudioMetadata,
```

On angular side use the same approach:

uploadFileCreateTable(payload) {

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('audio', payload.file);

const audioMetadata = {
  sessionId: payload.sessionId,
  strategy: payload.strategy
  ... //and so on
};
formData.append('audioMetadata', new Blob([ JSON.stringify(audioMetadata) ], {
  type: 'application/json'
}));

return this.http.post(`${this.api}/Verify`, formData);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to send `base64` string for your audio blob from client side( so convert your blob to base 64 string by using any `angular module`) then on your backend side you can process base64 string lik this.

```
    Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] decodedByte = decoder.decode(base64Audio.split(",")[1]);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("your audio file name");
    fos.write(decodedByte);
    fos.close();
```